# Diferença entre os parâmetros maxiter e maxfun na função fmin_l_bfgs_b

Tags: python, scipy

No [help](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html) da função:

```
maxfun : int
Maximum number of function evaluations.
maxiter : int
Maximum number of iterations.
```

Mas o que é o número máximo de iterações e o número de avaliação de funções?

Para mim, o número de iterações era diretamente relacionado ao número de avaliações da função, mas eles dão resultados diferentes. Como é calculado o número de avaliações de função?

Answer (score 0):

Posso estar errado, mas quando você otimiza uma função, você pode ter que avaliar o valor ótimo dos outputs, realizando diversas 'evaluations' a cada 'iteration'.

Em uma interação do algoritmo `L-BFGS-B` pode ter que realizar (e geralmente realiza) múltiplas avaliações/comparações de valores até chegar ao valor ótimo para os parâmetros.

O parâmetro `maxiter` controla o número de iterações que o algoritmo pode realizar.

Já o parâmetro `maxfun`, refere-se o número de avaliações/comparações que o algoritmo pode fazer, a cada iteração, acerca da função objetivo.

**Ou em outras palavras:**

O processo de otimização de uma função pode requerer ao otimizador, que este avalie o valor da função objetivo, diversas vezes com diferentes conjuntos de parâmetros.

O nº máximo de interações que o otimizador pode rodar é controlado pelo parâmetro `maxiter`.

O nº máximo de vezes que a função objetivo pode ser avaliada/testada, com diferentes conjuntos de parâmetros, é controlado pelo parâmetro `maxfun`.

**Por exemplo:**

Sabemos que a execução do algoritmo de otimização em uma determinada função objetivo vai levar 10 interações, com cada interação requerendo avaliação dos valores obtidos por 5 vezes, até chegar ao valor ótimo.

Temos então que o `maxiter` deve ser igual a 10 e o `maxfun` igual a 10*5 = 50.

Caso contrário a função não rodará o nº mínimo de vezes para ter seus parâmetros otimizados.